# update daysAvailableCounter vacation Request

Tags: bpmn, business-process-management, bonita, bpmn.io

anyone can help me pleeease , in leave request  when I do the first one a leave request the currentbalance(daysAvailable) updated but the second one back to the daysAvailableInitial

For exemple 
daysInitialValue = 60 
new request( NbreDays=5 ) --> daysAvailableCounter:60-5=55
second request (NbreDays = 3)--> daysAvailableCounter 60-3=57 shoud be do  daysAvailableCounter 55-3= 52

thanks in advance

this is my process.bos

https://www.dropbox.com/home?preview=DemandeConges-19.0.bos

Comment: it is resolved  . an error in the code of official example
                for (VacationAvailable va : currentlyExistingVacationAvailable) {
  alreadyKnownEmployeeId.add(va.bonitaBPMId)
  va.daysAvailableCounter = daysAvailableInitialValue
==>
 for (VacationAvailable va : currentlyExistingVacationAvailable) {
  alreadyKnownEmployeeId.add(va.bonitaBPMId)
  va.daysAvailableCounter = va.getDaysAvailableCounter()

Comment: Please write the solution as an Answer.

Answer (score 0):

In the official example we used a dedicated process to initialize the counter that should only be run once. It use the business variable default value to do so.

Then the process to create vacation request will use the business data created by the initialization process and update them. This achieve using operations defined on task.

If code [available on GitHub](https://github.com/Bonitasoft-Community/vacation-management-example) is not valid please open an issue on the project.